# I am having trouble writing code to solve a maze recursively (backtracking)

Tags: java, recursion, maze

I looked on the internet and other places (including my book), but I don't really seem to get the answer I am looking for. The big part that has kept me up until this terrible hour (5:25 am) is backtracking. How does this even work? I just put "return" when I'm blocked on all sides and it magically undoes my last move? I'm shaking my head in disbelief because I always thought as soon as you "return", your recursion unwinds completely.

I'm also a little miffed that my code is so long. My teacher told the class that it was supposed to be a short solution. Well, I had to load the maze, check for things, write the algorithm for checking directions (I just modified it to be recursive but I am almost 100% sure it is wrong). Not to mention initializing the array of objects and writing a specialized method for seeking a hyperspace spot to teleport to. Anyways, here it is. I am aware some of it does nothing. I'm not done with it yet, after all. http://pastebin.com/5wknVCWa And yes I paste it there because it really is somewhat large. Over 300 lines.

Comment: is it to hard to look at the questions with the tags you used for your own question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maze-solving

Comment: `return` only returns from the current method invocation, not from all of them.

Answer (score 3):

backtracking algorithms are short.  it does not have to be recursive (but it looks much nicer that way).  the main work you do is to write a reject function, that checks if the current decision is still ok.  if not, then you backtrack (ie return from single level of recursion) to the previous decision.

in a maze the reject function could be you just walked into a wall - or were eaten by a grue.  the accept function could mean you finished the maze and are done (or rescued the prince, etc)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

```
 procedure bt(c)
   if reject(P,c) then return
   if accept(P,c) then output(P,c)
   s ← first(P,c)
   while s ≠ Λ do
     bt(s)
     s ← next(P,s)
```